# How to get source html from ckeditor in angular2?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I'm trying to create a preview of a page and for that I need the html from ckeditor. I know there's a method getData() but idk what property to call it on.

Answer (score 0):

May be i don´t understand clearly what you are looking for,still i want to give it a try.

`controller.ready().then(function initialize() { 
          ['dataReady', 'change', 'blur', 'saveSnapshot'].forEach(function (event) {
            controller.onCKEvent(event, function syncView() {
              ngModelController.$setViewValue(controller.instance.getData() || '');
            });
          });`

here `controller.instance.getData()` gives you data on view on specific events like 'dataReady', 'change', 'blur', 'saveSnapshot'.you have to register your controller and attach it with this. which will give you access to data of the controller here.So you can try for any of these 'dataReady', 'change', 'blur', 'saveSnapshot'.to access those html.